# Get values from Paypal payment-intent multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, paypal

I want to implement the serverside-sdk from Paypal to my website. Everything works fine so far.

After the payment-intent got send to Paypal, I receive an array with information about the payment from Paypal.

If I `print_r` the object I got back it looks like this in my browser:

```
PayPal\Api\Payment Object (

    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [intent] => sale [payer] => PayPal\Api\Payer Object ( 

    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [payment_method] => paypal ) ) [transactions] => Array ( [0] => PayPal\Api\Transaction Object ( 

    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object ( 

    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [total] => 0.50 [currency] => EUR ) ) [related_resources] => Array ( ) ) ) ) [redirect_urls] => PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [return_url] => https://www.fabiansquinobal.com/addjob_submitted.php [cancel_url] => https://example.com/your_cancel_url.html ) ) [id] => PAYID-LSSMWWI9WR61061C3673442W [state] => created [create_time] => 2019-04-03T15:03:52Z [links] => Array ( [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object ( 

    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LSSMWWI9WR61061C3673442W [rel] => self [method] => GET ) ) [1] => PayPal\Api\Links Object ( 

    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [href] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-0RG36824VV460380F [rel] => approval_url [method] => REDIRECT ) ) [2] => PayPal\Api\Links Object ( 

    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LSSMWWI9WR61061C3673442W/execute [rel] => execute [method] => POST ) ) ) ) 
)
```

I am completly overwhelmed with that. I would need to know how I can get to the "[id] => PAYID-LSSMWWI9WR61061C3673442W" or generally extract information out of this "thing".

Regards

**EDIT:**

The `var_export` of the array looks like this:

```
PayPal\Api\Payment::__set_state(

    array( '_propMap' => array ( 'intent' => 'sale', 'payer' => PayPal\Api\Payer::__set_state(

    array( '_propMap' => array ( 'payment_method' => 'paypal', ), )), 'transactions' => array ( 0 => PayPal\Api\Transaction::__set_state(

    array( '_propMap' => array ( 'amount' => PayPal\Api\Amount::__set_state(

    array( '_propMap' => array ( 'total' => '15.00', 'currency' => 'EUR', ), )), 'related_resources' => array ( ), ), )), ), 'redirect_urls' => PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls::__set_state(array( '_propMap' => array ( 'return_url' => 'https://www.fabiansquinobal.com/addjob_submitted.php', 'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/your_cancel_url.html', ), )), 'id' => 'PAYID-LSSNC7I1CX40811F59322531', 'state' => 'created', 'create_time' => '2019-04-03T15:30:05Z', 'links' => array ( 0 => PayPal\Api\Links::__set_state(

    array( '_propMap' => array ( 'href' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LSSNC7I1CX40811F59322531', 'rel' => 'self', 'method' => 'GET', ), )), 1 => PayPal\Api\Links::__set_state(

    array( '_propMap' => array ( 'href' => 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-98A35361RF153213R', 'rel' => 'approval_url', 'method' => 'REDIRECT', ), )), 2 => PayPal\Api\Links::__set_state(

    array( '_propMap' => array ( 'href' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LSSNC7I1CX40811F59322531/execute', 'rel' => 'execute', 'method' => 'POST', ), )), ), ), )

)
```

An `echo` of the object looks like this:

```
{ "intent": "sale",

        "payer": { "payment_method": "paypal" },

        "transactions": [ { "amount": { "total": "0.50", "currency": "EUR" },

        "related_resources": [] } ],

        "redirect_urls": { "return_url": "https://www.fabiansquinobal.com/addjob_submitted.php", "cancel_url": "https://example.com/your_cancel_url.html" },

        "id": "PAYID-LSSNFSY6AJ60558N2288040L",

        "state": "created", "create_time": "2019-04-03T15:35:38Z",

        "links": [ { "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LSSNFSY6AJ60558N2288040L",

        "rel": "self", "method": "GET" },

        { "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5KK55362XB209301D",

        "rel": "approval_url", "method": "REDIRECT" }, 
        { "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LSSNFSY6AJ60558N2288040L/execute",

        "rel": "execute", "method": "POST" } ] 
}
```

Comment: What would the var_export of that array look like?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: We can't read that either. Can you paste the json string instead? I just want something that we can use and/or read. The formatting of your question is "lacking in quality"

Comment: Thats formulated pretty nicely. I try to set some breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either decode the string to an array and use:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo $arr['id'];
```

Or if you want it as an object:

```
$arr = json_decode($json);
echo $arr->id;
```

https://3v4l.org/bF2t9

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Andreas, is there a way for me, how I can identify an encoded json? How did you know? By simply looking at it?

Comment: Yes, just by looking at it (in a formatted way) see the link and uncomment the var_dump. Then you can see how the array nests and goes back to the main array again.